# Python Pandas: How the the last of rows timely close together within groups?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "group": [1,1,1,2,2,2],
    "update time": ["2019-01-01 12:00:00", "2019-01-01 12:01:00", "2019-01-01 15:00:00", "2019-01-01 15:01:00", "2019-01-01 15:02:00", "2019-01-01 15:04:00"],
    }
)
df["update time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["update time"])
df
```

[image]

Within `group` I want to look for updates timely close together (say within 5 minutes) and keep the last update. In other words: Within a group, keep entry if next update happened more than 5 minutes later. The desired outcome is:

[image]

When ignoring groups, this works fine:

```py
df["keep"] = df["update time"].shift(-1) - df["update time"] > "0 days 00:05:00"
df.iloc[df.shape[0]-1, df.columns.get_loc("keep")] = True # Keep last entry
```

How do I expand this so that it works with `df.groupby("group")`?

Thanks a lot!

---

Edit:
With the comment from @0x5453 I made up this solution:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "group": [1,1,1,2,2,2],
    "update time": ["2019-01-01 12:00:00", "2019-01-01 12:01:00", "2019-01-01 15:00:00", "2019-01-01 15:01:00", "2019-01-01 15:02:00", "2019-01-01 15:04:00"],
    }
)
df["update time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["update time"])

diff = abs(df.groupby("group")["update time"].diff(periods=-1))
df["keep"] = (diff > "0 days 00:05:00") | (diff.isnull())

df
```

Comment: You should be able to use something like `df.groupby('group')['update time'].diff()`

Comment: why is index 2 True?

Comment: Index 2 is True, because index 3 belongs to another group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll create a list of indices we need to keep, by forming chains of observations within 5 minutes of each other and taking the last one.

This becomes tricky because sometimes we need to keep the first observation within a group where the `diff` is not defined.

```
#df = df.sort_values(['group', 'update time'])
#df['update time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['update time'])

m = df.group.eq(df.group.shift(1))      # Indicates where groups change
s = df['update time'].diff().where(m)   # Time difference, within group only

idx = s.groupby([(s.gt('5min') | s.isnull()).cumsum(), df.group]).tail(1).index

df['keep'] = df.index.isin(idx)
```

---

#### Output

More rows for illustration

```
    group         update time   keep
0       1 2019-01-01 12:00:00  False
1       1 2019-01-01 12:01:00   True
2       1 2019-01-01 15:00:00   True
3       2 2019-01-01 15:01:00  False
4       2 2019-01-01 15:02:00  False
5       2 2019-01-01 15:04:00   True
6       3 2019-01-01 15:01:00   True
7       3 2019-01-01 15:21:00   True
8       4 2019-01-01 15:01:00   True
9       5 2019-01-01 15:21:00   True
10      6 2019-01-01 12:00:00  False
11      6 2019-01-01 12:01:00   True
12      6 2019-01-01 15:00:00   True
```